# Using normal JavaScript with Laravel NPM/WebPack Compliation

Tags: laravel

I am attempting to use normal JavaScript with NPM and WebPack.

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app

.js'], 'public/js').version()
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version();
```

In my app.js I added a simple test function:

```
var sayHi = function sayHi()
{
    alert('hi');
};
```

And I included it in a HTML page, and called

```
<script>
sayHi();
</script>
```

However, I receive the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHi is not defined
```

I believe that WebPack etc. hides it all from the global namespace. I have ensured the compiled JavaScript with `npm run watch` has been included.

I am looking for insight on how to proceed.

Comment: Because by using `var` you scoped `var sayHi` to the file in your case. You can do `window.sayHi = funcntion sayHi()...` and it will work.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I would vote you up but I'm new.

Comment: @devk Maybe add it as an answer?